# Why Visual Studio is not copying static files before running tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, nunit

We are currently facing an issue in Visual Studio (v15.7.2): when we are running the tests of our .NET Core project, if we only change the content of a static file (.sql, appsetting.json, .txt, etc), Visual Studio does not see the changes in the files, it uses the old version of it and the tests are not running correctly.

If this the normal behavior, how is it possible to change that and force Visual Studio to rebuild or at least to re-copy the static files and take the changes into account?

Of course, if we change the code, the project is automatically rebuilt and the new files are copied. This issue happens a lot because we are using SQL files to setup the database state before running our integration test.

Minimal project code to reproduce it is available here: https://github.com/Gerfaut/dotnet-core-test-static-files

Steps to follow:

- Open the project in Visual Studio 2017 and run the test → The project is built and the test is green ;
- Change the content of the file Project/wwwroot/static-file.txt to "﻿This is NOT a static content" ;
- Run the test → The test is still green although the content of the file has changed and should fail the test.

Thanks a lot for your help,

*Gerfaut*